# php curl returning empty array

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to get some webpage content using php `curl`.

I have this php code:

```
$target_url="http://me.dealintech.com/partho.php";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$file_contents=curl_exec($ch);
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = str_get_html($file_contents); 
$elem = $html->find('div[id=basic_info_content]');
echo "var_dump output: ";
var_dump($elem);
```

And the output I get is :

> > [ here I get the whole webpage contents I targeted ]
> >
> > var_dump output: array(0) { }

So I am getting all contents **but not the specific div content**. How I can get that using div id or/and class

Comment: add $html value in question

Comment: Just adding to @AmitRajput comment, `echo $html;` please. Does that div you are looking at show?

Comment: Yes. output of `echo $html;` is very large string. Rather you see http://dealintech.com/a.php which shows the output you are asking for.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option to make `curl_exec` return the contents of the URL rather than output it.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

If you're not using any other `cURL` options, you could instead use the simpler `file_get_contents`:

```
$file_contents = file_get_contents($target_url);
```

And Simple HTML DOM Parser includes a function that does this automatically for you:

```
$html = file_get_html($target_url);
```

Comment: that almost answered my question. But I am looking for **specific div content**. Can you say,how?

Comment: In my target page there's a div `id=basic_info_content`. I want to get text of that div. (Which I said in my question). Please give an idea

Comment: That part of your code should work fine. The only problem was the way you were getting the HTML.

Comment: You can also write it as `$elem = $html->find("#basic_info_content")`.

Comment: output of `$elem = $html->find("#basic_info_content"); print_r($elem); ` is very large. You can see here the output http://dealintech.com/a.php

Comment: Printing a node also prints all the nodes inside it.